# Is $P+1$ prime for the perfect number $P$ corresponding to the exponent $74207281$?

Tags: reference-request, perfect-numbers, primality-test

The even perfect numbers are closely related to the Mersenne primes. We currently know $51$ Mersenne primes and hence $51$ perfect numbers.

It has already been checked for which of those perfect numbers $P$ , the number $P+1$ is prime. The formula for $P$ is

$$P=2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$$ where $n$ is an exponent for which $2^n-1$ is prime.

The exponents $n=2,3,13,19$ are known to give a prime. For all other exponents non-trivial factors are known except of the $49$ th exponent $n=74207281$

> Has this case been checked by someone ? If not , I invite everyone to search a nontrivial prime factor.

According to my calculations , there is no prime factor below $2\cdot 10^{10}$ , nevertheless the chance of this number to be prime is extremely small.

Comment: Just to be clear (you sometimes use $P$ for a perfect number and sometimes for that $+1$) you seem to be asking about $2^{148414561} - 2^{74207280} + 1$

Comment: @Henry To clarify : The question is in short whether $$2^{74207280}(2^{74207281}-1)+1$$ is prime (equal to the your number, just written down slightly different). I hope for a nontrivial factor of this number, otherwise a primality test would be very time consuming (unless someone has already done this). Should this number be prime , it would be a new record prime , but the odds are clearly against this.

Comment: These numbers are also called Right Perfect Numbers (RPN). The status for RPN 74207281 is still unknown. No prime factors found below $5 \cdot 10^{14}$. See also discussion at mersenne forum [here](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=27917) and [updated list](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showpost.php?p=142828&postcount=10).

Comment: @Sil Fixed. In fact, the formula for $P$ was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [reported](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showpost.php?p=620622&postcount=22) by mersenneforum user Neptune just yesterday, this number is divisible by the $17$-digit prime $14344999215792989$, found using the elliptic curve method.  (Link posted by Martin Hopf in the comments.)

Comment: Thank you for the announcement! Indeed Neptune is my alias at mersenneforum. It is worth to mention that the [fast modular reduction with right perfect numbers](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showpost.php?p=613264&postcount=19) plays a key role here. Implementing it in the elliptic curve method made it possible to find a factor in reasonable time.

Comment: @MartinHopf Well now I wish I'd commented instead and let you post the answer.  Very nice work--I wouldn't have expected ECM to be practical for any numbers of this size.

Comment: All is fine. The ones who are interested will read the comments for sure. 
If it was an arbitrary number instead, we still could make use of Montgomery's great REDC algorithm to speed things up, although not to such an extent.